# How to find Area given Diameter

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor, unit-conversion

I need to convert diamter to area. I have (1/2)'' diamter acting on a steel cable. I need to calculate the stress, which is:

o- = Force/Area

The Force we know to be: F = 1000 lbs (pounds).

Perhaps, someone could help me calculate area from the given (1/2)'' diameter.

So I google:

http://www.onlineconversion.com/circlesolve.htm

It gives me .2 for (1/2)'' diameter. What is the forumlae that produces area when given diamter..?

Comment: Edited. If approved; remove -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Area  = \pi{r^2}=\pi{(\frac{d}2)^2=\frac{\pi}4d^2}$